# Submitting conference paper to Google Scholar when proceedings not available

Tags: conference, google-scholar

I presented a paper at a conference but the conference never got around to publishing their proceedings. They kept saying it was going to happen "soon" but after six months, I have lost hope.

Is there any way to submit such a paper to Google Scholar? It's not hosted anywhere and Google is an indexing service, not a paper repository. That makes me think the answer is no. However, I know the minds here will have the answer.

The paper is in education so Arvix is not really a solution here.

Answer (score 3):

This is not to your question, but:

You are too impatient. In the publishing industry, 6 months is not an incredibly slow turn-around time.

Comment: For a journal I can understand, but for conference proceedings?

Comment: Same thing. They only difference between journals and proceedings is how papers are collected, and that at least sometimes proceedings are one-off things. But the time line is not all that different.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Is it possible that the conference will never make their proceedings available on IEEE Xplore and similar platforms?

Comment: @a_sid -- nobody other than the editors can know. Email them and ask!

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I have emailed them several times but they have not responded to my emails. I just wanted to know whether or not it is a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

See [this link](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html) for some information:

> **Individual Authors**
>   If you're an individual author, it works best to
>   simple upload your paper to your website, e.g.,
>   www.example.edu/~professor/jpdr2009.pdf; and add a link to it on your
>   publications page, such as
>   www.example.edu/~professor/publications.html. Make sure that:
>
> a the
>   full text of your paper is in a PDF file that ends with ".pdf",
>
> b the
>   title of the paper appears in a large font on top of the first page,
>
> c the authors of the paper are listed right below the title on a
>   separate line, and
>
> d there's a bibliography section titled, e.g.,
>   "References" or "Bibliography" at the end.
>
> That's it! Our search
>   robots should normally find your paper and include it in Google
>   Scholar within several weeks.

If you’re not at a university, I reckon some place like academia.edu or researchgate.net might also be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Copyright permitting, you could always post it to a  preprint server that accepts publications from all disciplines. I quite like OSF Preprints: https://osf.io/preprints/

Google Scholar will then most likely index it soon after.