# How to add a paper to google scholar as "to appear"?

Tags: google-scholar

I had a paper in an IEEE conference which will appear in the proceedings. But the proceedings is not out yet.

Meanwhile, I would like to cite mentioned paper in another paper.

How do I do it? I want it to be added as "to appear in ..."

Can I add the article manually to google scholar?

If I do so, what happens if the proceedings out eventually? Will it be merged automatically?

I have read this [Submitting conference paper to Google Scholar when proceedings not available](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/117701/submitting-conference-paper-to-google-scholar-when-proceedings-not-available) but this doesn't solve my problem. Because of copy right I can not publish the pdf in preprint, research gate, etc.

Comment: How is the need to cite connected to adding the paper on Google Scholar?

Comment: To be clear, of course I can cite it manually anyway, right?

 but I want the citation to also appear in scholar so I want to somehow first add the paper to scholar and then cite it. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Meanwhile, I would like to cite mentioned paper in another paper. How do I do it? I want it to be added as "to appear in ..."

Cite the paper as you would any IEEE conference paper, omitting any information that you don't know (e.g., page number) and tagging "to appear" on the end.

> Can I add the article manually to google scholar?

If you want.

> If I do so, what happens if the proceedings out eventually? Will it be merged automatically?

It may or may not be automatically merged, we cannot predict how Google's algorithms operate.

> Because of copy right I can not publish the pdf in preprint,

Actually, you likely can, since many publishers let you publish preprints on personal websites.